# How to set an int parameter in sugar orm findwithquery method to retreive data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, database, android-sqlite, sugarorm

Guys I want to set an int parameter to the  findwithquery method in sugar orm  to retrieve data from sqlite database in android.
This is the query

```
List<cart> c=cart.findWithQuery(cart.class,
"Select * from cart where customer=? and status=?",1,"NOTPAID")
```

*the customer field is a integer field in the database

When I execute the above I get syntax error near "status"

Comment: If you don't mind can you add what is the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for hardcoded customer field 1

```
List<cart> c=cart.findWithQuery(cart.class,
"Select * from cart where customer=" + 1 + " and status=?", "NOTPAID");
```

For dynamic customer field

```
List<cart> c=cart.findWithQuery(cart.class,
"Select * from cart where customer=" + customerField + " and status=?", "NOTPAID");
```